# How to remove children of tree nodes with single child

Tags: algorithm, tree, tree-traversal, preorder

I have an array for pre-order traversal of a tree (node values are depth values). All I want to do is to minimize tree by removing the children of internal nodes having only one child.

As an example (a tree with max depth = 3)
[problem visualized here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShgbB.jpg) 
Input array: [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3] 
Output array: [0, 1, 2, 2, 1]

How should be the algorithm?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Can you recreate the tree from those information?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you've meant. From output array, it is no possible to create input tree, but it is not my purpose anyway. Could you explain more please?

Comment: The example doesn't match your description. You are deleting both children of the leftmost 2 node.

Comment: I agree, you should clarify the question. I answered for the example.

Comment: Actually, it shifts one level up (as I delete leftmost "1" node - the only node with single child). I do not delete the node in the 2nd level. Sorry for my possible bad explanation and English, could you help me how to explain such a problem?

Comment: @kfx, your solution works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple O(nlog(n)) average-case algorithm arises from attacking the problem by divide-and-conquer approach.

Start with `input_level = 0`, `output_level=0`, `left=0`, `right=n-1`.

In each of the recursive steps, count the elements with value `input_level+1` in the input array `A` in range [`left`, `right`]. These are the children of the current node. If there are no such elements, print `output_level` and return. If there is just one such element, "delete" the current node (i.e. do not print it), increase `left` by 1, and call the function recursively. If there are two or more such elements, print `output_level`, increase `output_level` by 1, and apply the function recursively to each of the intervals demarcated by the children elements. *Always* increase `input_level` when doing the recursive call.

For the example input `A=[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, first the algorithm would find elements with value 1, at indexes 1 and 5. Then it would print 0, increase `output_level` and `current_level` by 1, and call itself recursively two times: on ranges [1, 4] and [5, 7].

The complexity of this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case (for the degenerate tree that is in fact a list), but O(nlog(n)) on the average, as a random n-ary tree has height O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm runs in O(N). I guess I get it correct this time.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

void mark_nodes(const std::vector<unsigned>& tree,
                std::vector<bool>& mark) {
  // {depth, index, mark?}
  using triple = std::tuple<unsigned, unsigned, bool>;
  std::stack<triple> stk;
  stk.push({0, 0, false});
  for (auto i = 1u; i < mark.size(); ++i) {
    auto depth = tree[i];
    auto top_depth = std::get<0>(stk.top());
    if (depth == top_depth) {
      stk.pop();
      if (stk.size()) std::get<2>(stk.top()) = false;
      continue;
    }
    if (depth > top_depth) {
      std::get<2>(stk.top()) = true;
      stk.push({depth, i, false});
      continue;
    }
    while (std::get<0>(stk.top()) != depth) {
      mark[std::get<1>(stk.top())] = std::get<2>(stk.top());
      stk.pop();
    }
    mark[std::get<1>(stk.top())] = std::get<2>(stk.top());
    stk.pop();
    if (stk.size()) std::get<2>(stk.top()) = false;
    stk.push({depth, i, false});
  }
  mark[0] = false;
}

std::vector<unsigned> trim_single_child_nodes(
    std::vector<unsigned> tree) {
  tree.push_back(0u);
  std::vector<bool> mark(tree.size(), false);
  mark_nodes(tree, mark);
  std::vector<unsigned> ret(1, 0);
  tree.pop_back();
  mark.pop_back();
  auto max_depth = *std::max_element(tree.begin(), tree.end());
  std::vector<unsigned> depth_map(max_depth + 1, 0);
  for (auto i = 1u; i < tree.size(); ++i) {
    if (mark[i]) {
      if (tree[i] > tree[i - 1]) {
        depth_map[tree[i]] = depth_map[tree[i - 1]];
      }
    } else {
      if (tree[i] > tree[i - 1]) {
        depth_map[tree[i]] = depth_map[tree[i - 1]] + 1;
      }
      ret.push_back(depth_map[tree[i]]);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<unsigned> input = {0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3};
  auto output = trim_single_child_nodes(input);
  for (auto depth : output) {
    std::cout << depth << ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems not working properly. i.e. {0,1,2,1,2} gives output {0,1,2,1}. it should be {0,1,1} instead.

Comment: @guezara Yes. The case of leaf node seems difficult to handle.

Comment: @guezara Finally. I guess I get it correct this time.

Comment: O(N) solution would be perfect for me @Lingxi, as my data is really huge but I did not understand your solution with all details. i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] input gives output [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 ]. Instead it should be [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 ]. Can you guess why? Thanks

Comment: @guezara `mark_nodes()` is most probably correct, which marks the nodes to be trimmed. Problem is how to use that information to compute the final result. I guess I can't push it any further myself. Sorry about that. I've tried but failed. Yet, I do believe a linear time algorithm exists. Gonna leave the answer open here anyway. Hopefully, more capable people would see it and make it complete.